# Subset of a time series, bad value for start in windows function

Tags: time-series

this is my first post and I hope you can help.
I am trying to extract certain period from a time series.
My time series (tsSST) goes from 2011,1,1 to 2015,12,31 and I need to extract the period from 2014,1,1 to 2015,12,31.

That is my code and the error I am having:

```
tsSST<-ts(SST[,2], start=c(2011,1,1), frequency=365)
tsSST2<-window(tsSST, start=c(2014,1,1), end=c(2015,12,31), frequency=365)
```

Resulting Error message:

> Error in window.default(x, ...) : bad value for 'start'

If anyone can explain what is needed to be changed I'll appreciated that.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Your question does not have a statistical component and should be migrated to Stack Exchange's *Stack Overflow* site. SO is intended to be a resource for programming/coding questions like yours.